# NHibernate ISQLQuery SetParameter issue

Tags: nhibernate, parameters, isqlquery

This is probably fairly straightforward but i can't seem to find a reasonable explanation in any documentation.

I'm trying to use an NHibernate.ISQLQuery and using SetResultTransformer() to return a custom set of results from a custom SQL query. Like so:

```
    public virtual IList<T> GetSQLObject<T>(string sql, IDbParameter[] parameters = null)
    {
        ISQLQuery qry = _sess.CreateSQLQuery(sql);

        qry.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean(typeof(T)));    

        if (parameters != null) {
            foreach (IDbParameter parameter in parameters) {
                qry.SetParameter(parameter.Name, parameter.Value);
            }
        }

        return qry.List<T>();
    }
```

From looking at the examples, it seems that in the sql query I have to use parameters in the format *:param1* instead of *@param1* as I would in a standard SQL query. If i use the latter syntax in the query, it throws an error at qry.SetParameter().

Is there a reason why ISQLQuery/NHibernate requires them in this format and won't work with the normal syntax?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL Server uses @param, but not every other database does. For example, MySQL uses ?param

NHibernate allows you to swap out 1 database implementation for another with little to no reworking of your DAL. It sets the parameters based on the database you configured when you setup the NH Configuration.

*Edit: Also I think :param came about from Hibernate being targeted at Oracle when it was initially developed, since Oracle uses :param*

Answer (score 0):

Phil has answered the "why"; so perhaps I can recommend a "how"; why not just add a new extension method to the `IDbParameter` type (something like `.GetNHibernateName()` ) that will return the parameter name with the "@" replaced with a ":"; that should be trivial to implement.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this extension method?  Since the parameter name that we pass in doesn't include the prefix character ':' or '@', how are we overriding that internal prefixing character with the extension method?